# Position sticky with respect to parent container

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="
                width: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow-x: scroll;
              ">
  <div class="box" id="one">1</div>
  <div class="box" id="two">2</div>
  <div class="box" id="three">3</div>
  <div class="box" id="four" style="position: sticky; left: 0px">4</div>
  <div class="box" id="one">5</div>
  <div style="display: inline-flex">
    <div class="box1" id="three1" style="position: sticky; left: 0px">
      one
    </div>
    <div class="box1" id="four1">two</div>
    <div class="box1" id="two1">9</div>
    <div class="box1" id="three1">10</div>
    <div class="box1" id="four1">11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="two1">6</div>
  <div class="box" id="three1">7</div>
  <div class="box" id="four1">2</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve the same effect `'id=4'` sticky behavior for `'id=three1'`, As it has different viewport. Tried to apply `position:fixed` when reached most left. Didn't worked as expected
Can anyone help to resolve.